# gitlab zip file only contains .git file

Tags: zip, gitlab

I run GitLab 7.2.0 when I want to create a zip file from my repository as a release file. But when I click "Download .zip" the file only contains a .git file, not the code.

Is this the usual behavior? It seems weird to me, but maybe there is a fix which you guys probably would know.

Regards,
Jacob

Comment: No it's not normal. Is it reproducible on a repo on gitlab.com? I just testes on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-test - everything works as expected. Is there any information in the logs?

Comment: Some problem there but found the solution. I folder gets the .git in its name. Mac OS X interpreters this is a .git file and not as a directory.

I noticed this by opening the.zip on a Windows machine.

Comment: @Jacob So it's actually a directory but MAC interprets it a .git file? This is literally the only relevant answer I could find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the file and select "Show Package Contents"

You will then see all the files and you can pull what you need out.